# How are fMRI responses to auditory stimuli measured?

Tags: neuroscience, biophysics, experimental-design, experiment, imaging

How can fMRI experiments be conducted which measure the response to auditory stimuli (e.g. music) when the apparatus makes such loud, nasty, and distracting noises? Are there quieter MRI tomographs in the meanwhile, or must the stimuli (transfered by earphones) be louder than the noise of the machine? How to measure the effect of a whishper then?

Answer (score 1):

I could have found this article earlier, but as things go, I didn't. But possibly it contains most of what can be said to this question:

Jonathan E. Peellej, [Methodological challenges and solutions in auditory functional magnetic resonance imaging](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4139601/), Front Neurosci. 2014; 8: 253